# Fibonacci sequence in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

I am trying to build a fibonacci wrapper function that takes in multiple command line arguments and computes the associated Fibonacci number for each argument

Comment: Have you tried using `read` to convert the `String` to an `Int`?

Comment: What should happen if your command line arguments are not numbers?

Comment: Hint: if you use `map fibonacci . catMaybes . map readMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` on the list of strings, you’ll get a list of `Int` values that skips all non-integer inputs. You could also wrap `readMaybe` in a function that calls `error` on invalid input and also tells the compiler what type to read to.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `read` or `readMaybe` functions to get an `Int` from the `String`:

```
fibonacci_wrapper :: [String] -> Maybe Int
fibonacci_wrapper (x:_) =
    case readMaybe x of
        Just n -> Just (fibonacci n)
        Nothing -> Nothing -- read failed
-- Not enough args
fibonacci_wrapper _ = Nothing
```

However, if you want to take multiple arguments, you should return the rest of the argument list along with the `Int` result so that you can continue consuming arguments.

Answer (score 1):

**Wrapper** solution could be:

```
wrapperStringToInt :: [String] -> [Int]
wrapperStringToInt [] = []
wrapperStringToInt (x:xs) = (read x :: Int) : wrapperStringToInt xs
```

You could use tuples to return `fibonacci 4 is 3`. The function **`printFibonacci`** prints that for each tuple.

```
printFibonacci :: [(Int, Int)] -> IO ()
printFibonacci [] = return ()
printFibonacci ((x, z):xs) = 
    do  putStrLn $ "fibonacci " ++ show x ++ " is " ++ show z
        printFibonacci xs
```

The command

```
map f (wrapperStringToInt arguments)
    where
        f = (\ x -> (x, fibonacci x))
```

returns an array with tuples `( Input, Output )` (e.g. With `[3,4,5]` this command returns `[(3,2),(4,3),(5,5)]`).

```
main = do
    arguments <- getArgs
    printFibonacci $ map f (wrapperStringToInt arguments)
        where f = (\ x -> (x, fibonacci x))
```

After that, run in the terminal:

```
runhaskell Fibonacci.hs <INPUT>
```

(e.g. `runhaskell Fibonacci.hs 3 4 5`)

Finally, to execute this program like `./program 4 5 6`, you could write an executable bash program, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
runhaskell Fibonacci.hs "$@"
```

If error control is important you should use Maybe as other users have commented. I hope you find this information useful.